# Initializing a 2D vector with random values

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, stdvector

I'm trying to initialize a double vector array (a matrix indeed) with random numbers but I must be wrong with something and I haven't been able to find the solution here or in google.

I have the next 'standard' definition which initializes my Matrix with 0:

*Case 1:*

```
 int num_rows=5, num_cols=7;
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(num_rows, std::vector<int>(num_cols, 0));
```

So if I make something like that:

*Case 2*

```
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(num_rows, std::vector<int>(num_cols, rand()%100));
```

What I see is that `rand()%100` is called once so if it returns `34` then all my Matrix will be filled with that number.

At that point I've tried using the *Case 1* initialization and a double for with iterators like that:

```
for ( std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it1 = Matrix.begin(); it1 != Matrix.end(); ++it1 )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = (*it1).begin(); it2 != (*it1).end(); ++ it2 )
    {
        std::cout << (*it2) << "\n"; //With that I can see every value on the matrix... right now all 0 

    }
}
```

Now in that loop, I can't find the way to go item by item and assign them a new value.  I'm sorry as I'm conscient it's a really simple question but couldn't find it on google ...

As it2 is the var I have to use, if I try to make something like the next above it doesn't compile and even intellisense doesn't let me put de 'assign' (because I'm rally wrong ofc):

```
it2.assign(...) 
(*it2).assign(...)
it1->assign // Here intellisense works but i don't think this it my option.
//
Matrix(it2,rand()%100); // error

Matrix[it1][it2] = rand() % 100; // Desperate...like normal array?
Matrix.at(it2) = rand()%100;  
Matrix.at(it1).at(it2) = rand() % 100;
```

I assume that `assign` is the function I need in that case as insert will add new elements or maybe `at` but everything I try gives me an error and I don't know what else can I try or if maybe I have to think about it in a different way...

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators are like pointers. The simplest thing is to just assign `*it2 = rand() % 100` in your loop.

A slightly more complex thing would to use functions from `<algorithm>`

```
void fill_row(std::vector<int> & row)
{
    std::generate(row.begin(), row.end(), [](){ return rand() % 100; }); 
}

void fill_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>> & mat)
{
    std::for_each(mat.begin(), mat.end(), fill_row);
}
```

[std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) assigns to each element the result of calling it's function parameter.

[std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) calls it's function parameter with each element

Comment: Looks like the best one +1

Comment: Oh.. I see! I understood that iterator where like pointer but didn't know I could assign something with the simpliest way of `=`  hehe Ty so much!! I understand that there isn't a better way of making that without a double loop  right?

Comment: well I provided `fill_matrix` as a function that does the same thing, with no explicit looping

Comment: @Caleth Right! Let me make you a last question... why do you pass `[](){ return rand() % 100; }`?? I can't understand what it does and moreover why does that 'parameter' start with `[]()` empty

Comment: That is a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). It defines an anonymous function object, which can be called like an `int(void)` function

Comment: You could just as easily write `int next_int() { return rand() % 100; }`, although that adds a name to the scope it is in. You can easily run out of sensible names

Comment: @Caleth but then if you use `int next_int()` you will have to declare it before passing it as a parameter right? or could you just put that code where the `[]()...`is?

Comment: You define it in namespace scope, so `next_int` would precede `fill_row` which precedes `fill_matrix`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can supply a random value to vector constructor and expect random values for all elements. Instead reserve the vector size and then assign random values by dereferencing an appropriate iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd; 
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 100);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(5, std::vector<int>(7, 0));

    for (auto it1 = Matrix.begin(); it1 != Matrix.end(); it1++) {
        for (auto it2 = it1->begin(); it2 != it1->end(); it2++) {
            *it2 = dis(gen); // dereference iterator, set the value
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << *it2;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Here `it1` represents iterator to rows and is of type: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator` and `it2` represents iterator to individual elements and is of type `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: Wow, I'll have to check on google about random_device, mt19937 and uniform as I've never ever  read about it! Ty so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you are looking for a way to generate random matrix (where each element is random).

Here's how to do this:

```
int num_rows = 5, num_cols = 7;
// create Matrix filled with 0 (as you mentioned in Case1)
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(num_rows, std::vector<int>(num_cols, 0));
// Iterating over each row
for (auto it_row = Matrix.begin(); it_row != Matrix.end(); it_row++)
{
    // Getting each (i,j) element and assigning random value to it
    for (auto it_col = it_row->begin(); it_col != it_row->end(); it_col++)
    {
        *it_col = rand() % 100;
    }
}

// let's print the Matrix
for (auto it_row = Matrix.begin(); it_row != Matrix.end(); it_row++)
{
    for (auto it_col = it_row->begin(); it_col != it_row->end(); it_col++)
    {
        std::cout << *it_col << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why use double loop twice? :P   One question.. why do you use auto here? What is better to use std<vector> or auto? Never used auto before (I know what does) but never know if it is good to use it...

Comment: @Megasa3 double loop is used second time just to print resulting matrix, ofc you don't need to use it in your code. `auto` is used to make code more readable and convenient